# make generic regular expression in jmeter regex extractor

Tags: json, regex, jmeter, performance-testing

I have the following code snippet in my html response:

```
003cdiv  id\u003d\"d1f15ddf10691ed7%2?604?-1form
```

I extract the value of id which is

`d1f15ddf10691ed7%2?604?-1`

by the regular expression

```
003cdiv  id\\u003d\\"(.+?)form
```

My problem is, sometimes, the generated value becomes

```
d1f15ddf10691ed7%2?604?-1EVENT_ERROR
```

I know that this is because of an error but is it possible that I will still be able to get the id value using a more (somehow) generic way of a regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to update your regular expression as below:

```
id\\u003d\\"(.+?)(form|EVENT_ERROR)
```

Make sure, the template value of your Regular Expression Extractor is *$1$* to get the first group value.

I hope this help you.